# ASP.NET: Loop through database

Tags: asp.net, database, loops

I have a page right now that functions 100%, it updates a database , based on an id sent via querystring. Now, I am wanting to make this function perform for EVERY row in the database and without being sent a querystring.

```
 Dim amzRepeater As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem


    Dim myId As String = Request.QueryString("Id")
    Dim amzUrl As String = amzRepeater.Row("AmazonUrl")
    amazonURL.Value = amzUrl


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim aHtml As New HtmlWeb
    Dim aDoc As HtmlDocument = aHtml.Load(amazonURL.Value)


    Dim aNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
    aNode = aDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='olpDivId']/span[2]")
    Dim UsedPrice As String = aNode.InnerText
    Dim i As Integer = UsedPrice.IndexOf("$")
    UsedPrice = UsedPrice.Substring(i + 1)

    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("arprimaryConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Amazon SET AmazonUsedPrice = @AmazonUsedPrice, LastUpdated = @LastUpdated WHERE (id = @id)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmazonUsedPrice", UsedPrice)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdated", DateTime.Now.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", myId)

    Using con
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    MsgBox("Update Sucesfull.")
```

Comment: You want each row to have the same @AmazonUsedPrice?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just remove the *WHERE* clause from the SQL statement, and the *id* parameter.  This will update every row:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Amazon SET AmazonUsedPrice = @AmazonUsedPrice, LastUpdated = @LastUpdated", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmazonUsedPrice", UsedPrice)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdated", DateTime.Now.ToString)
```